# Get list of files within a time range based on file names containing timestamps

Tags: python, glob

[A simplified python project](https://replit.com/@ralphfehrer/GlobFilesWithinFileRange?v=1) with the structure

[image]

Contains a number of files with names encoding a timestamp using the format

```
MMDDYYYY_HHMMSS
```

E.g., the name of the first file contains the timestamp May 11th, 2023, 08:01:34.

What I need is a function with the signature

```
def get_files_between(starttime,endtime):
```

That returns all the file names within the range between starttime and endtime, where the starttime and endtime are given by hours and minutes.

For example,

```
get_files_between("0801","0802")
```

should return

```
['f_sometext_05112023_080134.csv','f_sometext_05112023_080155.csv','f_sometext_05112023_080218.csv','f_sometext_05112023_080225.csv']
```

It is realatively easy to realise something like that for a one minute interval like 08:01, using glob:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(pathname="Files/f_*_*_0801*.csv")
print(files)
```

How can this code be generalised to intervals containing several minutes?

Comment: so, the date is not important, just the time of day right?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way :

```
from pathlib import Path
​
def get_files_between(starttime, endtime):
​
    out = [f.name for hm in [starttime, endtime] #`hm` for hour-minute
           for f in Path("Files").glob(f"f_*_{hm}*.csv")] #adjust the pattern if needed
​
    return out
```

​
Output :

```
get_files_between("0801", "0802")
​
['f_sometext_05112023_080134.csv',
 'f_sometext_05112023_080155.csv',
 'f_sometext_05112023_080218.csv',
 'f_sometext_05112023_080225.csv']
```

A more robust approach would be to use [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_files_between(starttime, endtime):
    s, e = datetime.strptime(starttime, "%H%M"), datetime.strptime(endtime, "%H%M")

    hmins = [(s + timedelta(minutes=i)).strftime("%H%M")
            for i in range((e-s).seconds//60+1)]
    
    out = [f.name for hm in hmins for f in Path("Files").glob(f"f_*_{hm}*.csv")]

    return out
```

Output :

```
get_files_between("0800", "0802")

['f_sometext_05112023_080001.csv',
 'f_sometext_05112023_080134.csv', # <-- not retrieved by the 1st approach!
 'f_sometext_05112023_080155.csv', # <-- not retrieved by the 1st approach!
 'f_sometext_05112023_080218.csv',
 'f_sometext_05112023_080225.csv']
```

*Tree used :*

```
Files
┣━━ f_sometext_05112023_080001.csv # <-- added by me to test the `timedelta` approach
┣━━ f_sometext_05112023_080134.csv
┣━━ f_sometext_05112023_080155.csv
┣━━ f_sometext_05112023_080218.csv
┣━━ f_sometext_05112023_080225.csv
┣━━ f_sometext_05112023_080323.csv
┗━━ f_sometext_05112023_080455.csv
```